# Steps for doing a clean uninstall and reinstall Jupyter-Lab and then ipyleaflet on Ubuntu Linux 20.04

Tags: jupyter-notebook, leaflet, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Folks,
I got an error when I tried to create a map in ipyleafltet so I tried the following steps to completely reinstall jupyter and ipyleaflet. Now I don't get an error but ipywidget just hangs "Loading widget...".  I know that a clean reinstall works because i did it previously but i seem to be missing one step.  Don't think it is relevant, but in case it i'm running on running on an AWS EC2 instance

Best,
Tom (tom@geospatialtechnicalsolutions.com)

**Uninstall**
source v

- List item
- env
- jupyter labextension uninstall @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
- jupyter labextension uninstall @jupyterlab/geojson-extension
- jupyter labextension uninstall @jupyterlab/google-drive
- jupyter labextension uninstall @jupyterlab/toc
- jupyter labextension uninstall @parente/jupyterlab-quickopen
- jupyter labextension uninstall @qzchenwl/jupyterlab-manager
- jupyter labextension uninstall jupyter-leaflet
- jupyter labextension uninstall jupyterlab-execute-time
- jupyter labextension uninstall jupyterlab-interactive-dashboard-editor
- jupyter labextension uninstall jupyterlab-s3-browser
- jupyter labextension uninstall jupyterlab-skip-traceback
- jupyter labextension uninstall jupyterlab-tabular-data-editor
- jupyter lab clean
- pip3 uninstall jupyterlab
- python3 -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console notebook qtconsole - - - nbconvert nbformat
- pip3 install pip-autoremove
- pip-autoremove jupyter -y
- pip-autoremove jupyter-core -y
- rm -rf /Users/$user/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions
- rm -rf /Users/$user/Library/Jupyter/nbsignatures.db
- rm -rf /Users/$user/Library/Jupyter/notebook_secret

**install**

- pip3 install jupyterlab
- pip3 install notebook
- jupyter notebook
- pip3 install voila
- jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
- sudo jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
- pip3 install gmaps
- jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps
- sudo jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps
- pip3 install ipyleaflet
- jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager jupyter-leaflet
- git clone https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet.git
- cd ipyleaflet
- jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
- jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
- jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager js
- jupyter labextension install @bokeh/jupyter_bokeh
- jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
- jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/geojson-extension
- jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/google-drive
- jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc
- jupyter labextension install @parente/jupyterlab-quickopen
- jupyter labextension install @qzchenwl/jupyterlab-manager
- jupyter labextension install jupyter-leaflet
- jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-execute-time
- jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-interactive-dashboard-editor
- jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-s3-browser
- jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-skip-traceback
- jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-tabular-data-editor

Answer (score 9):

not sure if this helps, but what I would have done is to probably do a

```
jupyter lab clean --all
```

instead of simply `jupyter lab clean` and on top of that,
I would just

```
pip3 install jupyterlab --force-reinstall
...
jupyter lab
```

without `pip install notebook` or `jupyter notebook`

Comment: It would be helpful to explain the *why* behind those decisions.